# Eraser tool on drawing while keeping border

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I'm making a 2D map drawing tool and have a problem. The border around the painted "land" acts as a "coast". When the user paints in more water, the land should be removed/replaced by the water brush, but the coasts should adapt with the change (because coasts are drawn in real-time).

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Cartographer
{
    public partial class testform : Form
    {

        private GraphicsPath _drawingPath = new GraphicsPath();
        private Point lastMouseLocation;
        private bool drawing = false;

        public testform()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void testform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Paint += Testform_Paint;
            this.MouseMove += Testform_MouseMove;

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        }

        private void Testform_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                drawing = true;
                _drawingPath.AddLine(lastMouseLocation, e.Location);
                //_drawingPath.AddEllipse(new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(10, 10)));
                Invalidate();
            }

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None && drawing)
            {
                drawing = false;
                _drawingPath.StartFigure();
            }
            lastMouseLocation = e.Location;
        }

        private void Testform_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            //e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
            //e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            //e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Brown)))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 55))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);
            }

            using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Brown))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(b, 50))
            {
                p.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Round;

                e.Graphics.DrawPath(p, _drawingPath);
            }

        }

        private void btnErase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<PointF> ptsList = new List<PointF>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                ptsList.Add(_drawingPath.PathData.Points[i]);
            }

            _drawingPath = ErasePointsFromPath(_drawingPath, ptsList.ToArray<PointF>());
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        private GraphicsPath ErasePointsFromPath(GraphicsPath path, PointF[] toRemove)
        {
            GraphicsPath ret = new GraphicsPath(
                path.PathData.Points.Skip(20).ToArray(), 
                path.PathData.Types.Skip(20).ToArray());

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

I want my software to have borders like this, even when the water is brushed over land:

[image: pic 1]

Right now it looks like this (which is fine, it's for testing) but I have no way to fine-tune that little river/lake in the middle of the land mass because the coasts will disappear if I simply paint over it.

[image]

I have another working version of this that works with `GdipWindingModeOutline`so if there's a way to do this with that I can adapt.

For the record I've tried erasing points from the `GraphicsPath` but that erases huge chunks instead of the simple "eraser tool" type of functionality I'm aiming for.

Thank you!

Comment: Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: @LarsTech asked how to erase points from a GraphicsPath. I realized that erasing points from a GraphicsPath takes chunks away and doesn't match what I'd like done. Really just need a MSpaint style eraser that will maintain my border and that's it :(

Comment: On another note Bitmap.SetPixel() seems to have the behaviour I want out of an eraser (though the border is still an issue) but everyone says to not use it because it's inefficient...

Comment: You should use LockBits in place of SetPixel.